# Uncaught error injector modulerr in angular.min.js 40

Tags: angularjs

am getting the following error

> angular.min.js:40 Uncaught Error:            [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$injector/modulerr?p0=ngAnimate&p1=Error%…lime%2520Text%25203%2FPackages%2Fmysamplefolder%2Fangular.min.js%3A21%3A19)

my code is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.insert').click(function(){
     $('.addItems').show( "slow" );
            });
  $('.close').click(function(){
  $('.addItems').hide('slide',{direction:'down'},'slow');
  });
        });


         function dataTable($scope)  {
        $scope.items = [
   {
        id:'11111',
        name:'JohnDoe Number1',
        city:'Angel',
        state:'AA',
        phone:'111-111-1111'
    },
        {
      id:'22222',
        name:'JaneDoe Number1',
        city:'Bigfoot',
        state:'AB',
        phone:'222-222-2222'
    },
    {
        id:'33333',
        name:'JohnDoe Number2',
        city:'Comfy',
        state:'AC',
        phone:'333-333-3333'
        },
        {
        id:'44444',
        name:'JaneDoe Number2',
        city:'Dreamy',
        state:'AD',
        phone:'444-444-4444'
        }];
        $scope.addItem = function(item) {
           $scope.items.push(item);
           $scope.item = {};
        }
        $scope.removeItem = function(index){
            $scope.items.splice(index,1);
        }
      };
```

Comment: may be you don't inject ngAnimate dependency in your app.

Comment: your code snippet is unclear. did you define module for your app?

Comment: pl share your code until we be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Include ngAnimate module on your .html file via `<script>` tag.